# close spinner view after item is selected

Tags: android

I have a spinner in my fragment . I want that when i click on any position in spinner the spinner view should get close and spinner text should change according to my selection. I my case i have to have outside the spinner to close it and its text remain unchanged.

```
public SmsBatchSpinnerListAdapter(Context context, BaseActivity activity, 
ArrayList<String> student, ArrayList<String> studentId, ArrayList<String> 
updatedSmsNumber, ArrayList<String> updatedUserId) 
 {
    super(context, R.layout.sms_batchname_spinner, stBatch);

    this.student = student;
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.updatedUserId = updatedUserId;
    this.updatedSmsNumber = updatedSmsNumber;

 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    String name;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_batchname_spinner, parent, false);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.hiddenlayout);
    studentBatch = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    studentBatch.setTag(position);
    name = student.get(position);
    spinner = (Spinner) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    studentBatch.setText(name);


    studentBatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String idIndex = studentId.get(position);
                if(!idIndex.equals("0")){
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    getStudentName(studentId.get(position));



                }
                else{
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"Please select an item ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure, there is no method of `spinner` exist to close itself.
and, 
I think `studentBatch.setOnClickListener(...)` is the method that prevents spinner from getting closed. Instead you can set `setOnItemSelectedListener(..)` to the spinner to get the event when spinner item is selected, and that will close your spinner as well (kind of system behavior).

Further,
`spinner.setSelection(int position)` may do the trick. 
i.e.

```
studentBatch.setOnClickListener(....) {
    spinner.setSelection(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bind arraylist to spinner using setAdapter method.You will get selected item in spinner and dialogue will be gone.